# Установка Убунты на ноутбук с флешки

Tags: ubuntu, usb, linux

Мне посоветовали две утилитки для установки убунты с флешки (первую благополучно забыл, вторая - LiLi USB Creator). Вроде процесс создания проходит нормально, но при запуске с флешки на ноуте (через бут меню) у меня появляется черный экран и мигающий курсор. И ничего. И так было на обеих утилитах. Кто может знать, в чем проблема?

Comment: Флешка нормальная? И как успехи с UNetBootin?

Answer (score 3):

1) Для установки с флешки "утилитки" не нужны, главное, чтоб комп поддерживал загрузку с флешки.
2) Желательно создавать так, как описано в [Download Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download), раздел 2 - "Burn your CD or create a USB drive". Там выбрать вашу ОС, в которой будете создавать образ на флешку, поставить галочку USB и посмотреть, как создать образ на флешке.
3) Лично у меня возникла проблема с установкой Ubuntu 10.04 с флешки. Последняя версия (11.04) с флешки установилась отлично, без проблем.

Comment: Ну винду с флешки ставил нормально.
Спасибо, буду пробовать.

Comment: Тогда пункт 1 можно пропустить :)

Comment: опять та же ерунда...

Answer (score 1):

Флэшку в FAT и используй UNetBootIn